# Correct akka remote settings when migrating play project

Tags: java, playframework, akka

Project is moving from Play version 2.3.0 -> 2.7.4 and Akka version 2.3.3 -> 2.5.27

As well as running the web app on port 9000, the old project had the following settings:

```
project_name {
  akka {
    loglevel = DEBUG
    loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    actor {
      provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
      guardian-supervisor-strategy = "project_name.common.supervisors.ServiceSupervisor"
    }
    remote {
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "localhost"
        port = 9090
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering how to update this to work with the new versions, since play now uses akka-http server by default instead of netty (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/Migration26#Akka-HTTP-as-the-default-server-engine)

I've tried to follow these instructions to continue to use netty (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/NettyServer) but I keep getting the following error:

```
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:9090
```

So I think it may be easier to migrate the settings to use the default akka-http server instead, however the settings from the original are specific to netty and I can't find any docs on what to use in their place

Answer (score 0):

I think this blog might solve your use case: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/SettingsAkkaHttp

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, I've seen that blog, it doesn't seem to cover my use case though